# Creating file for each user with list of files to be backed up

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that creates txt file for each user with list of files from home directories to be backed up.

I created so far below script:

```
for user in ${user_names[@]};
do

user_home=$(awk -F ':' -v user="${user}" '$1==user {print $6}' /etc/passwd )

ls -p | grep -v / >${user_home}/backup.txt
done
```

The result is that system creates file backup.txt in both users directories (user1 and user2), but both backup.txt files contain list of files from user1.

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: on each pass through the loop you never designate a directory in which to run `ls` (eg, you never `cd` to a new directory) so for each pass through the loop you're running `ls` in the same directory; from the description it sounds like you're sitting in `user1's` home directory when you run your script

Comment: `ls -p "$user_home"`? I suggest to use `find`. See `man find`.

Comment: I havbe used ``` find ${user_home} -user ${user} -ls >${user_home}/backup.txt ``` but the result gives lots of files with their directories any idea how I can create rsult with just list of files?

Comment: You should provide an [mcve], so we know how you define, and what you put in `user_names[@]`.